# Airflow: How would I write a Python operator for an extract function from BigQuery to GCS function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am writing an Airflow DAG, which will extract a table from BigQuery to a GCS Bucket, but I am unsure what parameters I need to include in my `PythonOperator`.

So far, I have written the following function to execute the code that will extract the table from BigQuery to a GCS Bucket:

```
def extract_table(client, to_delete):
    bucket_name = "extract_mytable_{}".format(_millis())
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = retry_storage_errors(storage_client.create_bucket)(bucket_name)
    to_delete.append(bucket)

    # [START bigquery_extract_table]
    # from google.cloud import bigquery
    # client = bigquery.Client()
    # bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
    project = "bigquery-public-data"
    dataset_id = "samples"
    table_id = "mytable"

    destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, "mytable.csv")
    dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

    extract_job = client.extract_table(
        table_ref,
        destination_uri,
        # Location must match that of the source table.
        location="US",
    )  # API request
    extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.
```

And, this is the `PythonOperator()` I have written, but I do not know what parameters I need to include:

```
extract_bq_to_gcs = PythonOperator(
task_id="bq_to_gcs",
python_callable=extract_table
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the `BigQueryToGCSOperator` without the need of using a custom function.

Parameters include the dataset/table you want to use as the source data, destination bucket, compression format, export format, delimiter...

Example of use :

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.bigquery_to_gcs import BigQueryToGCSOperator
...
bigquery_to_gcs = BigQueryToGCSOperator(
    task_id='bigquery_to_gcs',
    compression='GZIP',
    export_format='CSV',
    field_delimiter=',',
    print_header=True,
    source_project_dataset_table=f'{YOUR_DATASET_NAME}.{YOUR_TABLE}',
    destination_cloud_storage_uris=[
        f'gs://{YOUR_DATA_EXPORT_BUCKET_NAME}/{YOUR_EXPECTED_FILE_NAME}-*.csv.gz',
    ],
)
```

`BigQueryToGCSOperator` documentation with all parameters could be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_gcs/index.html)